# using SELECT inside an UPDATE query

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I tried doing this query but it doesn't work... can any one help me

```
(SELECT (r.fare-r.fare*(t.discount/100)) FROM ccard AS c, downer AS d, 
    typepolicy AS t, 
rates AS r
WHERE c.cardno=Enter_card_no and d.deviceno=Enter_device_no and 
    d.routeno=r.routeno and c.type=t.type );

UPDATE bank 
SET amount = amount-[the_result of above select query]
WHERE accountno=(select c.accountno from ccard c where cardno=Enter_card_no);
```

So i tried doing

```
UPDATE bank 
SET amount = amount-(SELECT (r.fare-r.fare*(t.discount/100)) FROM ccard AS c, 
    downer AS d, typepolicy AS t, rates AS r
WHERE c.cardno=Enter_card_no and d.deviceno=Enter_device_no and 
    d.routeno=r.routeno and c.type=t.type )
WHERE accountno=(select c.accountno from ccard c where cardno=Enter_card_no);
```

but it gives an error

> "Operation must use an updateable query"

Comment: I haven't puzzled out your subselect, but are you sure you can't retrieve the value from source data in tables related by a JOIN? And if you use that, you could try the Access/Jet/ACE DISTINCTROW predicate to try to force updatability. Absent that, a temp table may be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, on the subject of query updatability, if you join your tables using a WHERE clause, the query will not be updatable.  For example, rather than

```
FROM downer AS d, rates AS r
WHERE d.routeno=r.routeno
```

you should use

```
FROM downer AS d INNER JOIN rates AS r ON d.routeno=r.routeno
```

Second, is [bank] a one-row table?  Or do you really mean to set the amount column to the same value for all rows?

Third, without knowing how to join all the tables in your example, it's not possible to write an updatable query to do what you want.